# previously defined macro disappeared after including a header file

Tags: c++, c, macros

I have the following code:

```
#ifndef min
#define min(a,b) (((a)< (b)) ? (a) : (b))
#endif

int test(){
    return min(0,1);
}
```

Which works OK. However, if I include some header file (from a graph database, the content of this header file can be found here: http://www.sparsity-technologies.com/dex), the compiler complains that min is not defined, like Dex.h just cancelled the effect of my marco definition.

However, Dex.h doesn't contain any undefined statements. I couldn't move the macro definition, because it is actually included in another header file.

What's wrong and what should I do?

```
#ifndef min
#define min(a,b) (((a)< (b)) ? (a) : (b))
#endif

#include "gdb/Dex.h"

int test(){
    return min(0,1);
}
```

The compiler error I get is:

```
 test.c:9:16: error: 'min' was not declared in this scope
```

Comment: I'm kind of confused why you put the macro before the include anyway. And there are `std::max` and `std::min`. No need to make a macro with a conflicting name.

Comment: well, did it?  does Dex.h do anything to undefine min?

Comment: @xaxxon, I wouldn't be surprised if it did because of the windows.h one or an equally plaguing header.

Comment: No. Dex.h doesn't do anything like that. It does define its own namespace though

Comment: @yangsuli does it have any includes in it?

Comment: min and max are the macro from some legacy code, and I don't want to go through all the trouble of changing all the code which used that macro

Comment: also, please post the actual compiler error

Comment: it includes the following headers: <errno.h>, <signal.h> , <execinfo.h>, <stdlib.h>, <sys/types.h> <db.h> and <unistd.h>

Comment: is it possible that you're never defining it in the first place?  Perhaps something else is using an identical header name and you're ifdef'ing it out?

Comment: or maybe the define is changing the dex code in such a way that it is causing problems?  run it through the precompiler(only) and see what the output is.

Comment: No, that's not possible. Because I am showing the test code I wrote. I defined min, included "Dex.h", then it just doesn't work

Comment: Well, run it through the precompiler and let's see what you end up with.

Comment: Well, precompiler does give a line of #undef min, I am still having trouble figuring out where exactly this comes from though

Comment: well, what file does it look like it came from?  remember, the precompiler is VERY dumb.  It just starts at the first line of your first file and goes a line at a time.  When it sees an include, it jumps immediately, and when the include is done, it goes to the next line in the original file.  So what file does it seem like the undef is in?

Comment: ..or just put the output somewhere

Comment: http://www.2shared.com/file/s4CViuAb/test.html here is the output of precompile

Comment: "Well, precompiler does give a line of #undef min" -- wow, who could have predicted that?

Comment: # 1862 "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.5.1/../../../../include/c++/4.5.1/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/c++config.h" <== that's your file.. but I have no idea why this exists, what it does, or why this other thing includes it.

Comment: Ugh, please, *please* make macros look like macros by naming them in all uppercase.  Otherwise you're asking for trouble later when someone tries to use `std::min`, tries to name a variable `min`, or uses your `min` macro not expecting it to evaluate its arguments multiple times. (Conversely, things that aren't macros shouldn't be named in all uppercase, although many people have unfortunately perverted that to include non-macro constants.)

Comment: It's frustrating that you accepted the answer from the guy who just guessed at what the problem was instead of the answer that actually specifically described exactly what your problem was and took the time to get to that answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably, that header file `#undef`-fed `min` (either directly, or via another header file that it included).

Here are three solutions (in increasing order of preference):

1. Move your `#define` below your `#include`.
2. Use a function/template instead of a macro.
3. Use `std::min`, which can be found in the standard `<algorithm>` header.

Comment: Since I am dealing with legacy code, and #define is embedded in some header file, 1 is not possible. It seems like 3 requires changing a lot of code which uses this macro, and 2 means defining a set of functions for different datatypes?

Comment: @yangsuli: For (1), you could simply manually add *another* definition of the macro.  For (2), you could define a function template.

Comment: You are right. I am going with (1) and add another definition. Thanks you! I am just annoyed by the fact that including a header file has some unexpected effect...

Comment: @yangsuli "1 is not possible" -- Of course it is ... just move the include of the header file that defines min to after the include of Dex.h

Comment: @yangsuli: This is one good reason to avoid macros wherever possible, especially in C++ where namespaced functions are available...

Comment: @yangsuli " I am just annoyed" -- welcome to the world of programming (and the C preprocessor).

Comment: Is it safe for me to redefine the min macro? Seems like c++config.h undef'ed it for a reason...

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you're including `c++config.h`, which says:

```
00307 // This marks string literals in header files to be extracted for eventual
00308 // translation.  It is primarily used for messages in thrown exceptions; see
00309 // src/functexcept.cc.  We use __N because the more traditional _N is used
00310 // for something else under certain OSes (see BADNAMES).
00311 #define __N(msgid)     (msgid)
00312 
00313 // For example, <windows.h> is known to #define min and max as macros...
00314 #undef min
00315 #undef max
```

Looking further, it seems that's included by string which is included by

```
# 39 "dex/includes/dex/gdb/common.h" 2
```